# C#: convert a stream of bitmap images to avi file

Tags: c#, .net, video, stream, video-streaming

My application receives a sequence of images (BitmapImage) from an external device with rate 30 fps.

I need to create an avi file from this images and then, save it on filesystem. How can I obtain this result? Are there any C# libraries can I use for this purpose?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Look into the [AVIWriter](http://www.aforgenet.com/framework/docs/html/5fedbbbe-6d28-5f69-35a2-9d7119544a2d.htm) class of Aforge.Net.

Comment: AForge is GPL/LGPL licenses family. Beware!

Answer (score 5):

Check out the [SharpAvi](https://sharpavi.codeplex.com/) library I've written for my projects. It supports large file sizes (no 2GB limit).

Comment: SharpAvi uses Microsoft.Contracts.